# Typedef of anonymous class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any difference in any aspect (syntactic limitation, performance, etc.) between the following two definitions?

```
using Foo = struct { int a, b, c; };

struct Foo { int a, b, c; };
```

(I'm asking because the first form is aesthetically more uniform when put among a lot of `using` declarations.)

**EDIT:** The post linked to in the comment doesn't exactly answer my question. I'm more concerned about how the above two definitions differ in terms of *usage*, whereas that post mainly answers how they are different in terms of, well, what they are, I think.

Comment: Ah, there probably will be when the Reflection TS comes to fruition.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: @user2176127 No, take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 13):

Here are some differences I can think of:

- (obvious) You can't declare any constructors, a destructor, or an assignment operator for an unnamed class.
- You can't forward-declare an unnamed class, including as a friend of another class.
- You can't mark an unnamed class `final`.
- `struct Foo` can be declared in the same declarative region as a function or variable named `Foo`, although, obviously, you shouldn't do this. `using Foo = ...` does not allow you this freedom.

Comment: Also: "(§ 9.4.2.4 [class.static.data]) Unnamed classes and classes contained directly or indirectly within unnamed classes shall not contain static data members."

Comment: @AndyG Clang seems to [allow it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd7e45aec6546ba30) but not gcc.

Comment: Can you also not use `struct Foo` to refer to the class?

Comment: @immibis when I tried it, I got an error that the using declaration was redeclaring `Foo` as a different kind of name...

Comment: @Brian I mean `using Foo = ...; struct Foo instanceOfFoo;`. I presume that doesn't work but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @immibis As far as I can tell, you're not allowed to have the `using Foo = ...` declaration in the same declarative region as a declaration of a variable or function named `Foo`. This is because the special exception in [basic.scope.declarative]/4 only applies for "a class name or enumeration name that is *not a typedef name*".

Comment: @Brian Yeah... so what about a variable of **type** `struct Foo`? And is such a variable of type `Foo` as well? I assume not.

Comment: @immibis Oh, you are saying that you cannot use a typedef-name in an elaborated type specifier. Good point.